# How to place React Select Menu

Tags: css, reactjs, dropdown, react-select

I have the following example that I'm trying to fix in my project.
So `page-wrapper`'s height is supposed to emulate a page that has some content on it, hence the `height` CSS property.
I placed `select-container` in the middle intentionally to have space both above and below it.
If I open the menu for example when I land on the page, so no scroll in yet, instead of opening it up top, ReactSelect is opening it at the bottom and scrolling me down to it.
I tried `menuPlacement = "auto"` prop as you can see because from what I've seen in the documentation, it should do the positioning automatically, but it doesn't seem to work.

My Component

```
import ReactSelect from "react-select";

const options = [
  { label: "No 1", value: "test_1" },
  { label: "No 2", value: "test_2" },
  { label: "No 3", value: "test_3" },
  { label: "No 4", value: "test_4" }
];

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="page-wrapper">
      <div className="select-container">
        <ReactSelect options={options} menuPlacement="auto" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.page-wrapper {
  min-height: 180vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.select-container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I have a Sandbox code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-kare-9ke19) if needed.

Comment: Trying your code in the sandbox, it seems to work fine for me.
it opens the menu, scolling the view and make the options appear

Comment: @Filtenborg But I don't want it to scroll the view, I want it to open it on top or on bottom. Let's say, when you're at the top of the page so no scroll at all, if you open the menu it should place it at the top because there's not enough space below it.

Comment: @Filtenborg, the problem is that, if you open the menu, it is displayed at the bottom of the input, instead of at the top. The strange this is that, if you open the menu before to scroll the page, it is displayed on top, after scrolling, it is opened at the bottom, even if you scroll up again. Wired!

Comment: @kristalshards ah okay i misunderstood what you were trying to achieve, my bad

Comment: Tried again after refreshing the page, now is showing at the bottom even without scroll, don't know why it was acting differently before the refresh.

Comment: change menuPlacement "auto" to "top"

Comment: @GurulingKumbhar, this will force the menu to be always on top. User want the menu on top only if needed.

Answer (score 8):

Well, even if this options seems to be not so clear, it actually fixes the issue:

```
<ReactSelect menuPosition="fixed" options={options} menuPlacement="auto" />
```

By the way, read carefully here about the implications:

https://react-select.com/props

`menuPosition` property documentation.

With `absolute`, as per default (and not enough space after the input):

[image]

With `fixed` (and not enough space after the input):

[image]

If there is enough space after the input, menu is rendered after the input.

**Explanation**

Seems that the `menuPosition` decide how the menu should be considered "out-of-space", similar to CSS, in some way. If `absolute`, it refers to the space available in the parent container (that, in your case, since the `height` is `180vh`, according to the code you shared, is enough, unless you resize the page to make it smaller), if `fixed`, it refers to the space available in the visible part of the screen.

**Edit**

After reading the comments to this answer, even if I think that, in my opinion, this solution is over-complication something potentially not so relevant from an UX point of view, a possible fix is the following:

```
<ReactSelect options={options} menuPlacement={shouldBePlacedOnTopInstead ? "top" : "auto"} />
```

with `shouldBePlacedOnTopInstead` state computed using `window` scroll and visible screen related properties.

Comment: This looked like it solved the issue, but it brought new bug. If you open the menu, then scroll down/up, the menu will stick to its position.

https://i.imgur.com/GkJCyt3.png

Comment: This solve the issue by itself, so what you asked for. What you added additionally here in the comments seems to be not feasible with the library. My suggestion is to try with some real content in the page and check if the "issue" happens in a real situation. Another advice, `* { <margin_stuff> }`... please, don't do that, please! XD

Comment: Hmm, would it be possible if I make use of another library, like react-popper maybe?

Comment: And, of course, if, with real data, you are not getting issues, move back to `absolute`.

Comment: Well, `react-select` is a good library, my impression is that you are over-complicating for something that is unlikely to happen in a real scenario, and, at the end, not so blocking from an UX point of view (`react-select` is scrolling your page automatically even if the menu is displayed after the input).

Comment: Well, it's not my choice really, it's how it has been decided by the UX team so I can only try to implement it.

Comment: This happens what UX/UI team and developers team don't talk each other ahahahah If this requirement is crucial, no other option is available using `react-select` and this happen with real data, then you can try with another library, but you may have the same problem or other new problems.

Comment: Yeah well I am still trying to figure out a way to implement this with ```react-select```. I feel the documentation, especially the ```props``` documentation is incomplete and should include a bit more detail.

Comment: @kristalshards, I added some considerations in my answer, even if this can not be an optimal way to enforce the usability.

Comment: Appreciate it. Do you know where else I can try my luck and ask if there is a solution, with a quick response? I tried Googling the issue all day long.

Comment: @kristalshards - on page/window scroll event, you can close the menu by setting 'menuIsOpen' to false